# Vector calculations

Tags: vectors

[image: Rectangular field]

Say you have a Hiker $H$ walking at a constant velocity of $1.2\vec i - 0.9\vec j.$ Now say you have a rectangular field $OABC$ (the one above) with $OC$ due north and $OA$ due east, and at $12$ noon hiker $H$ is at the point $Y$ with the position vector $100 \vec j$ relative to the fixed origin. What would be the position vector of $H$ at time $t$ seconds after noon?

Furthermore, now say that you have another hiker $K$ is at the point with the the position vector $9\vec i + 46\vec j$, and has a constant velocity of $0.75\vec i + 1.8 \vec j.$ How would you show that at time $t$ seconds after noon, $\vec{HK} = (9-0.45t)\vec i+(2.7t-54)\vec j?$

So far I have tried the following things:

- Used the equation $r = r0 + vt$, to calculate the new position vector for hiker $H$ and got the answer as $r = 1.2t\vec i + (100 + 0.9t)\vec j$, which wrong for the first question apparently.
- For the second question I have no idea on where to start.

Comment: What do the ** mean?  Please use MathJax to format questions on this site. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have tried to use mathjax

Comment: The $i$ and $j$ are the basis vectors, right?  It doesn't make sense to talk about $1.4\vec i - 0.9\vec j$ m/s.  Meters per second is a speed, not a velocity.  So I guess you just mean a constant velocity of $1.4\vec i - 0.9\vec j$

Comment: yes I mean the velocity, my bad

Comment: Please verify that I haven't changed the intent of your question when I reformatted it.  Note how to write vectors in MathJax.  (Of course, some people write $\mathbf i$ or $\hat i$ instead of $\vec i.$  That's just a mtter of taste, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I verify that you have just reformatted the question, but how do i actually solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you just substituted into the the formula wrong.
You want $\boxed{100\vec j + t(1.2\vec i - 0.9\vec j)}$

I'm not sure what your problem is with the second part of the question.  You find the position of $K$ just like you find the position of $H$.  Is the problem how to compute $\vec{HK}?$  Remember that $\vec{HK}$ is the vector that takes you from $H$ to $K,$ that is, $H + \vec{HK} = K.$  Now solve for $\vec{HK}.$

Comment: Ok, I see what I need to do, thanks

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, you should accept it by ticking the check mark.  That way, others know it's been resolved.